# How to show folder of folder as a list in UITableView - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I am making an application that have a lot of static data. The data consists of images and text (each text file consists of multiple strings), and it will be hundres of items. I have the folders sorted in this way:

```
- Category
- - Name 1
- - - Image1.png, text1.strings
- - Name 2
- - - Image2.png, text2.strings
```

Then i want to show each folder of the category as its own row in a tableview. Is this a bad way to do it, any other preferred way to do it? If not how do you do this in Xcode with Swift?

Also would it be possible to make this searchable in the future?

Comment: Why not display like https://github.com/Augustyniak/FileExplorer, levels are individual tableview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cell.indentationLevel = 1 // Your indentation level
```

**UPDATE**

```
    @IBOutlet weak var tblView: UITableView!

    let tblData:[[String:Any]] = [["title":"Category", "indentationLevel":0],
                                  ["title":"Name 1", "indentationLevel":1],
                                  ["title":"Image1.png", "indentationLevel":2],
                                  ["title":"Name 2", "indentationLevel":1],
                                  ["title":"Image2.png", "indentationLevel":2]]

    // UITableView delegate methods
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tblData.count
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell  = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")

        cell?.textLabel?.text = tblData[indexPath.row]["title"] as? String ?? "NA"
        cell?.indentationWidth = 10
        cell?.indentationLevel = tblData[indexPath.row]["indentationLevel"] as? Int ?? 0

        return cell!

    }
```

[image]

**NOTE:**

You can use plist to store your static data instead of array of dictionary

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I am not sure how I'm supposed to use this.